# watchOS 2 compatible iOS

Tags: ios, watchkit

What is the minimum iOS version required to be on iPhone to make it compatible to watchOS 2 ?

I thought it was iOS 8.2, but the Xcode is defaulting to 9.0 when the project with watchOS 2 is created.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to have iOS 9 installed in order for your iPhone to communicate to the watch. This is due to some new functions and features introduced in WatchOS 2 that need information from your iPhone. Also to install WatchOS 2 you need a phone running iOS 9 Beta or higher.

Hope that helps,
Julian

Answer (score 1):

I would be real careful here.

I have spent almost two days trying to get Xcode 7 Beta 3 stable with IOS9 and WatchKit 2.

It just won't communicate properly and as you can't downgrade from WatchKit 2 you get stuck in an infinite loop of frustration.  It's all spit and wire at this point.

Had to use a back up iPhone, re-install Xcode 6 and .... wait for it .. bought another watch on Ver 1.1 so I can get a project out the door.

Big and expensive problem and solution although I will pass the iWatch onto one of our other developers when I am done.

Talk about bleeding edge.